# Sending Mail on Windows 2008 R2

Tags: email, windows-server-2008-r2, smtp

I have a single server, no AD installed, and I use it to allow my customers to connect via Remote Desktop and run a custom application.  I've got a feature in the application that will send a report via email, and as such the application launches the default mailto application setup in Windows.  Currently I have to install and configure Windows Live Mail to get this feature to work, however, installed Windows Live Mail for all of the 200+ users will eat up LOTS of space (I think around 300MB per user).  I'm searching for another solution, I've tried several standalone, send only smtp programs, but I can't get them set as the default email program, I'd even be okay with install Windows Live Mail once and having everyone use the same profile to send.  Again, they will only send an email, never receive and the reply to email is noreply@domain.com.  Anyone got any ideals?  I've got an image of the server setup in VirtualBox for testing any suggestions.
Thanks
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

Sending SMTP email is simply depositing a [correctly formatted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol), uniquely named file on the mail server. You could create the message as a text file, and send it to the mailserver.

A more elegant way is to use the [.NET platform](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/432854) or [C++](http://www.example-code.com/vcpp/smtp_simpleSend.asp) to create the message string and to send it to the mailserver.